# passwordless ssh access on mac os x mavericks

Tags: macos, ssh

I have tried to setup passwordless ssh on my mac using resources from web (setting the authorized keys to my public key).

first time I ssh into my own machine (ssh user@mymachine) I am able to login without ssh.

The next time I do this I am asked for the passphrase.

I followed the same procedure on my linux machine and things work fine. Not sure what I am missing. Any help is appreciated.

First time execution of "ssh -v localhost"

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /Users/<usrname>/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 433
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to localhost ([::1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Last login: Mon Feb  9 17:22:22 2015
```

Second time "ssh -v localhost"

```
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 433
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphr`enter code here`ase for key '/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Please kindly help.  Please let me know if I need to post any further information

Comment: Also one more thing I found is the first time I do "ssh-add -l" I see a valid identity. But once I ssh into the same machine and do "ssh-add -l" it says could not open connection to your authentication agent

Comment: Possibly answered here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106107/cannot-unlock-password-protected-ssh-key-in-os-x-mavericks